# Calling method from another class confusion (Robot class)

Tags: java, oop, methods

So I'm a little confused here, I had my first Object Oriented Programming java class the other day, and I decided that I need to practice a lot, since we go by the "Top-Down" design, which basically means that we first write the main program block using any methods we want, then write the definitions of these methods in a new class.

So I decided to play with the robot class in a MMO game I play, basically my plan was to just have my character randomly go from map to map, the first thing I did was just a simple mouse movement to the coordinates where a "gate" was in my game and then click on that gate to open the locations where I could move to, and it works fine if I use this code :

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

    public class Move {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Robot sW = new Robot();

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            sW.mouseMove(262,105);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            sW.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
            sW.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
            Thread.sleep(5000);



      }
    }
```

However since like I said I wanted to practice the Top-Down design, I had to make my main method much cleaner, so I tried the following :

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Gater sW = new Gater();

        sW.moveToGate();
    }

}

package test;

import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Gater {

    public void moveToGate(){

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        mouseMove(262,105);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

Now from what I gathered from the class, something like "mouseMove();" should have worked (but it doesn't) because since we were working with "Karel the Robot" using a method "move();" instead of "robot.move();" was totally fine, now my question is, am I actually missing something, or it's not actually "legal" in the "real" java world ?

And if it's not, is there any way for me to pull off what I wanted ?

Thanks.

Comment: in the first example you called mouseMove on a Robot. In the second you expect this method to be in "Gater" where it isn't it your example

Comment: Who is Karel? Other than that, you should use an IDE for programming and use a feature called "Refactor/Extract method...". That will create a reusable method but keep your code intact.

Comment: You have totally removed the Robot. You're just importing the class but do no longer create an object of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys, I still can't +1 you, but I will once I reach enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second attempt you are trying to call methods of the `Robot` class from the `Gater` class without supplying a `Robot` object.

You must create a Robot instance :

```
public class Gater {

    public void moveToGate(){
        Robot robot = new Robot ();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        robot.mouseMove(262,105);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that if I create another robot  inside the Gater, then I wouldn't be able to call the method moveToGate() from the main method, but it works just fine, thanks a lot !

Comment: if you want to use the same robot object as in your main method you could also give your gater class the robot through constructor or as method parameter like moveToGate(Robot robot)